# Is there a way to remove individual trees from a forest in the randomForest package in R?

Tags: r, random-forest, cart, max-margin

I am trying to implement the ideas in this paper: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0925231212003396.

This requires me to be able to remove individual trees from the forest and reclassify my training data for each removal. I've been using the randomForest package in R and had a comb through the manual but couldn't find any way of running the forest with a subset of trees, or even with an individual tree. There is a getTree function but that only gives a matrix of the node structure of the tree.

Is there any way to do this, either in randomForest (preferably) or via another random forest implementation (e.g. scikit-learn)?

Comment: Welcome to the site, @Spy_Lord. This question seems to be *only* about how to do this in R. Thus, it may be off-topic for CV (see our [help page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help)); but could be on-topic on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/). If you have a statistical question about RF, please edit to clarify; if not, we could migrate it for you (*please don't cross-post*). However, it will need a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/) to be on-topic there; so you'll need to show what you've tried so far & add a `dput()` of your data.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about statistics within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: Ah OK, my apologies. I would be alright with a solution outside R, so I suppose it overlaps slightly between CV and Stack Overflow. However user31264 looks like he's given me a workable solution anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One idea is, instead of creating one forest with N trees, create N "forests" of 1 tree each by calling `randomForest()` N times. Then you could manipulate them as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which language you are more familiar with.

`randomForest` package implements the original Fortran version of Breiman's random forest. You should try to modify the Fortran code then.

`party` packages has everything implemented in C. So, you can try to modify the C code.

WEKA `RandomForest` is implemented in Java and involves the classes `Bagging` and `RandomTree`.

Honestly, I am more familiar with Java and I would use WEKA then. I actually implemented some ensemble pruning techniques in WEKA and it was pretty simple.